# How to decorate a recursive function with caching in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, caching, recursion

We're going to make a decorator, caching computed results of deterministic functions (for simplisity let's assume one-argument functions).

In common case is could be done this way:

```
function makeCacheable(origFunc){
  let registry = {};

  return function (a){
    if (a in registry){
      return registry[a];
    }

    let res = origFunc(a);

    registry[a] = res;

    return res;
  }
}
```

A problem appears when `origFunc` is recursive: only top-level calls go through the wrapping cache, but the rest of recursive call stack doesn't meet the cache. No need to explain why this happens. I wonder **is there a natural way to make a recursive function cacheable in the same manner**?

```
function fibonacciF(n) {
  if (n <= 2) return 1;

  let a = 1, b = 1;

  for (let i = 2; i < n; ++i){
    [a, b] = [b, a+b];
  }

  return b;
}

function fibonacciR(n) {
  return n <= 2 ? 1 : (fibonacciR(n-1) + fibonacciR(n-2));
}

let fiboF = makeCacheable(fibonacciF); // OK
let fiboR = makeCacheable(fibonacciR); // actually is not what expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it work, if you would use the same (function) variable for storing the decorated version of it. To allow for returning back to the original, you could add a property `original` to the function object:

```js
function makeCacheable(origFunc){
  let registry = {};
  let f = function (a){
    if (a in registry){
      console.log(`retrieving value from registry[${a}]`);
      return registry[a];
    }
    let res = origFunc(a);
    registry[a] = res;
    return res;
  }
  // Add property for exposing the original function:
  f.original = origFunc;
  return f;
}

function fibonacciR(n) {
  console.log(`Called fibonnacci(${n})`);
  return n <= 2 ? 1 : (fibonacciR(n-1) + fibonacciR(n-2));
}

// Demo illustrating the registry is being used:
console.log('Call fibonnacciR(5) with cache turned on:');
var fibonacciR = makeCacheable(fibonacciR);
var f5 = fibonacciR(5);
console.log(`Result: fibonnaciR(5) = ${f5}`);

// Demo illustrating the function can be restored:
console.log('Call fibonnacciR(5) with cache removed:');
fibonacciR = fibonacciR.original;
f5 = fibonacciR(5);
console.log(`Result: fibonnaciR(5) = ${f5}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The function calls a function named `fibonacciR`. If you want to make this call go through the cache, you have to overwrite `fibonacciR`:

```
fibonacciR = makeCacheable(fibonacciR);
```

> Is there a natural way to make a recursive function cacheable in the same manner?

No. In general, a function implementation cannot be inspected, and it doesn't make a difference whether it's implemented recursively or with a loop or something else. Using pure functional programming, we can only use the whole function as a building block for the cached version (`fiboR`), but we cannot alter its behaviour or take only parts of the function unless the implementation is cooperative (e.g. by using some kind of [recursion operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) that can be user-supplied).

In the above solution, we break these rules by overwriting a variable that is used inside the function, but this is not always possible even in JavaScript.